# Connect FireDAC to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, delphi, firedac, delphi-10.3-rio

I'm currently trying to connect FireDac to a local SQL Server database but I can't seem to find the `MSSQL` driver ID in FDConnection1. I'm using the Community Edition of Delphi.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to check if Community Edition can connect to SQL Server at all. Embarcadero often limits connectivity to RDBMS in the Community editions

Comment: I don't think that is an option as noted in the [editions matrix](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/product-editions)

Comment: The editions matrix shows that Delphi Community connects only to a limited number of databases on the local machine. It doesn't even allow a remote connection to MySQL

Comment: You can connect to SQLServer using ADO components (named dbGO in Delphi) which are included in CE.

Comment: You didn't gave any feedback. Is it now working? If it does, are you doing like I said and use ADO components?

Comment: oh sorry, yes, you are right, sql Server databases ar not supported by FireDAC, so I used ADOConnection and all is working well, sorry I completely forgota about you